# Keras + TF, why is my model too big?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am using TF as a backend to Keras. I am using custom loss functions so I essentially use Keras as a wrapper for TF. I have a big model, which consists of 4 smaller ones, where 3 of them are pre-trained and loaded while the fourth gets trained.

The issue is, that when calling

```
self.session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
```

TF ends up with an error of trying to allocate too much memory on the GPU. The model itself has around 280 000 000 params (70 mil are trainable), and the TF graph has 1 000 000 000 variables. That's where the math doesn't add up.

Allocating 1 billion floats should take up around 4 GB of memory. And TF has 5.3 GB of VRAM available. The 1 billion variables should afaik include all stored activations and gradients and optimizer params (1 per trained param, using rmsprop).

There are very few activations because I only use quite small conv layers, so the activations for the whole thing per 1 sample should take around 6.5 MB and I'm using batch size of only 32, so 208 MB total.

Do you have any idea what's going on here? Does the model just barely not fit or is there a bigger problem somewhere?

Any advice appreciated!

EDIT: The model definition code: https://pastebin.com/6FRczTc0 (the first function is used for the 4 submodels and the second one puts them together into the bigger net)

Comment: Could you provide us with the model definition?

Comment: It is a lot of code because the shape of the model is quite unorthodox, it is used for deep RL, there are spatial and non-spatial inputs and outputs which means that they are combined in a weird way (broadcasting non-spatial inputs into 2D shapes without insane overhead requires weird workaround). I have put the code into pastebin though, see here https://pastebin.com/6FRczTc0

Comment: When you say "1 000 000 000 variables", do you mean a billion individual `tf.Variable` objects containing one `float32` element each, or a smaller number of  `tf.Variable` objects containing a larger number of floats each? If the variables are very small, you might be seeing fragmentation due to alignment requirements.